# Capturing lambda fails to capture named variable of a range-for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 fails to compile the following snippet with the `/std:c++14`:

```
[] {
    int values[] = {1,2,3};

    for (int n : values)
    {
        [&] {
            std::cout << n << std::endl; // 'n': undeclared identifier
        }();
    }
}();
```

In other hand it seems to compile with gcc and clang. Is it a bug in MSVC? What could be a workaround?

Comment: Works as expected for gcc/clang: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/717727e3e6d85fc0).

Comment: Try `[&]() { ...`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It still does it in the latest-and-greatest, 2017 Preview, 15.6.1. I submitted a bug report. We'll see what they say. The problem seems to be that the variable is declared in the range-based for-loop.  The following compiles and runs:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [] {
        int values[] = {1,2,3};
        const auto e = std::end(values);
        for(auto it = std::begin(values); it!=e; ++it) {
            auto n = *it;
            [&] {
                std::cout << n << std::endl; 
            }();
        }
    }();

    return 0;
}
```

So does this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [] {
        int values[] = {3,2,99};
        const auto e = std::end(values);
        for(auto it = std::begin(values); it!=e; ++it) {
            [&] {
                std::cout << *it << std::endl;
            }();
        }
    }();

    return 0;
}
```